# angularjs : pass argument to dynamic directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this simple directive:

```
app.directive('string', function () {
    return{
        template: '<input id="{{field.name}}" name="{{field.name}}" type="text" value="{{field.value}}"/>',
        restrict: 'E',
    };
});
```

That I'm creating in a controller:

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.steps;i++){
   var step = $scope.steps[i];
   var element = document.createElement(step.type);

   var compiled = $compile(element)($scope);
   $(document.body).append(compiled);
}
```

this outputs a textfield without a value. How can I give my directive the `'step'` variable and print it out in the text field as `step.value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use `ng-repeat` for this

`<string ng-repeat='field in steps'></string>`

**Update**: Doing what `ng-repeat` does

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.steps;i++){
   var childScope=$scope.$new();
   childScope.field=$scope.steps[i];
   var element = document.createElement(field.type);

   var compiled = $compile(element)(childScope);
   $(document.body).append(compiled);
}
```

Comment: But not all fields in steps are strings :)

Comment: use it with `filter` `'field in steps|filter:{type:"string"}'`

Comment: Or you can even use `<string ng-repeat='field in steps' ng-if='field.type=="string"'></string>`

Comment: but what I want is to retain the order in which they are in the array, I'd feel stupid writing <string> and then <option> and then <whatever> for each different type. I want to do it programmatically.

Comment: Surely what I'm asking above is possible?

Comment: You would have to create new scope so that the variable used in directive template do not conflict for multiple directive. You directive requires a property called `field` on the scope.

Comment: Can you show how I can create new scope with field in it and pass it to directive?

Comment: That works :) thank you! If I have some more time, I will try your first suggestion too, as it may be the nicer code.